# Non-commercial C# Library to format Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I have a list of reports that are exported to excel through some reporting services, and on my server i need to loop through these spreadsheets and perform additional formatting e.g.

1) hide columns
2) rename sheets
3) freeze panes
4) set default zoom, print size, etc.
5) save as html or convert to plain text file

So far i've done everything with interop and it works great but as you know microsoft shuns interop use on servers (and yet doesn't provide any replacement!). getting excel installed on a new server in the future will also be an uphill battle.

i've googled and stackoverflowed a fair bit and found some possible ones :-

I've tried NPOI which seems great but i encountered exception after exception trying to open my spreadsheet (first a overflow exception which i fixed, then a 'cell content more than 8552 bytes exception' which i could not).

I've tried excel library but there's a complete 100% lack of documentation. Also i found after formatting my spreadsheet that it does not retain it's original formatting.

Anyone knows of any good exhaustive free library or excel formatting for C#?

edit: unfortunately i left out the part which mentions i have to work with 97-2003 format so epplus is out of the question

Answer (score 5):

One approach to working with Excel files is to use the [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124). This requires working with Office 2007 or higher. The beauty of it is that instead of going through the Interop, you work directly against the xml file for the Excel document, which makes it a good option for server usage. The downside is that the way the files are organized is fairly different from the way it is presented through Interop, so figuring out what is what can be a challenge. I haven't used it specifically for formatting, but I worked with it for creating or editing documents via C#, and it's blazing fast.

Answer (score 4):

I use EPPlus. Simple but gets the job done!
http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: edit: unfortunately i left out the part which mentions i have to work with 97-2003 format so epplus is out of the question

Answer (score 2):

To some extent, MSFT has started to embrace server side excel, with their [MS HPC Excel integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.hpc.excel.exceldriver(v=vs.85).aspx). Nonetheless, you may be interested in [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) - "Create advanced Excel 2007/2010 spreadsheets on the server"

> EPPlus is a .net library that reads and writes Excel 2007/2010 files
> using the Open Office Xml format (xlsx).

#### EPPlus supports:

- Cell Ranges
- Cell styling (Border, Color, Fill, Font, Number, Alignments)
- Charts
- Pictures
- Shapes
- Comments
- Tables
- Protection
- Encryption
- Pivot tables
- Data validation
- Many more...

Comment: edit: unfortunately i left out the part which mentions i have to work with 97-2003 format so epplus is out of the question

Answer (score 1):

I used this one long time ago and it was super simple to use and very fast:

http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/ExcelXmlWriter/

Comment: i tried and this it's giving me a invalid character exception i'm not sure on what ... i think it's because of the XML conversion?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with xls (97 to 2003) you may want to try

http://npoi.codeplex.com/
[NPOI (nuget)](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/NPOI)

Works well for me in a limited scenario. You may also want to look at:

[ExcelLibrary (source)](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) by Artiom Chilaru 
[ExcelLibrary (nuget)](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/ExcelLibrary)

which is very fast and efficient.